# Unexpectedly shrunk window

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, tcp, kernel

I run a major media upload/download site and I noticed these:

Is this serious or background noise due to the big file sizes and is there any tweaks I can add to /etc/sysctl.conf to improve and prevent issues?

```
[8822139.804040] TCP: Peer 177.47.116.196:53829/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2513116350:2513136117 (repaired)
[8822140.944041] TCP: Peer 177.47.116.196:53829/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2513116350:2513136117 (repaired)
[8822143.224052] TCP: Peer 177.47.116.196:53829/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2513116350:2513136117 (repaired)
[8822147.776079] TCP: Peer 177.47.116.196:53829/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2513116350:2513136117 (repaired)
[8822156.896049] TCP: Peer 177.47.116.196:53829/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2513116350:2513136117 (repaired)
[8822175.136049] TCP: Peer 177.47.116.196:53829/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2513116350:2513136117 (repaired)
[8900596.808027] TCP: Peer 101.109.227.138:56284/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 1388148754:1388196670 (repaired)
[8900598.444020] TCP: Peer 101.109.227.138:56284/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 1388148754:1388196670 (repaired)
[8914737.204037] TCP: Peer 2.238.243.60:63238/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2810470657:2810491097 (repaired)
[8914738.004046] TCP: Peer 2.238.243.60:63238/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2810470657:2810491097 (repaired)
[8971335.364038] TCP: Peer 93.41.29.194:52424/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 4213166081:4213167541 (repaired)
[8971336.188080] TCP: Peer 93.41.29.194:52424/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 4213166081:4213167541 (repaired)
[8971337.840029] TCP: Peer 93.41.29.194:52424/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 4213166081:4213167541 (repaired)
[8973358.684040] TCP: Peer 101.109.225.96:50436/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 51484237:51532153 (repaired)
[8973361.684045] TCP: Peer 101.109.225.96:50436/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 51625081:51670093 (repaired)
[8973363.248026] TCP: Peer 101.109.225.96:50436/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 51625081:51670093 (repaired)
[8973366.376022] TCP: Peer 101.109.225.96:50436/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 51625081:51670093 (repaired)
[8973372.640024] TCP: Peer 101.109.225.96:50436/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 51625081:51670093 (repaired)
[8973385.152034] TCP: Peer 101.109.225.96:50436/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 51625081:51670093 (repaired)
[8973410.144024] TCP: Peer 101.109.225.96:50436/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 51625081:51670093 (repaired)
[8984154.940026] TCP: Peer 94.21.56.15:54897/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 2953312133:2953554053 (repaired)
```

Comment: Check this link you get know more details: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/unexpectedly-shrunk-window-747972/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Welcome to the Internet. It's perfectly normal for other machines to break the rules when they're talking to you. You can't fix the world, nor do you need to.